# Cookie or header to send own API to prevent Google Cloud Identity Aware Proxy (IAP) 302?

Tags: cookies, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-iap

I have setup Cloud IAP on a development environment (spun up with Kubernetes and using Let's Encrypt) and everything is working fine.

The setup is pretty basic for this app:

1) An `API` that has a number of REST endpoints and a persistent data store, in project **A**

2) A `SPA` front end app that utilizes said `API`, in a different project **B**

In my browser (tried Chrome and Firefox), I can authenticate my Google user in both apps via the IAP screen (by going to each domain in a browser tab), but once I try to use the `SPA` and *it* attempts requests to the `API`, I see the network requests 302 redirect to the Google IAP sign-in page.

**Question**:
Is there a header or cookie that needs to be sent over via the `API` requests on behalf of the user so that IAP allows pass-thru?

**Note**
I see these two cookies btw `GCP_IAAP_AUTH_TOKEN` and `GCP_IAAP_XSRF_NONCE`.

Comment: Regarding this issue, in the long run I opted to do an IP whitelist for my API instead ... but still want to come back to this.

I was working on a library that would help with this, and would automatically add the header to your API requests (was using native fetch but could extend to other libraries).

But the problem I had was also my usage of Web Sockets, which doesn't allow custom headers to be sent over.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's protected with IAP, "API" or "SPA"? If it's SPA, IAP should work as normal. If it's API, your best option today is to use https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto to have SPA authenticate to API, and maybe also have it pass down https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/signed-headers-howto so that API can separately verify the end-user's credentials.

Passing down GCP_IAAP_AUTH_TOKEN from SPA to API won't work, we strip that before passing the request to the end-user application for security reasons (in case the transport between the load balancer and the application is HTTP, just to make life a *little* harder for an attacker.)

Comment: In this case, both the SPA and API are protected with the IAP system.

Comment: Got it. In that case, I'd suggest having SPA authenticate to API using the service-account auth instructions, and also in that call SPA should include the X-Authenticated-User-JWT it got from IAP. SPA can validate that JWT and use it as proof that the end-user initiated the request to SPA. This isn't a *strong* mechanism, as those tokens don't provide strong prevention against replay or tampering -- i.e. someone with control of SPA still has a lot of power -- but it at least gives you some rudimentary end-user credential checking.

Does that work for you?

Comment: Yes that sounds reasonable, let me try it out!